# Can some one tell the difference between mat-form and form?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms

Can someone tell the differences between the  and  tags? Which is better to use with Angular 4?

Answer (score 2):

mat-form is the wrapper for HTML form in Angular Material. Material team customized the Form API's for Angular Material Form Controls, Validations. Each Form Control will follow the same syntax mat-input, mat-checkbox. Which is the wrapper for each Input form controls specific to Angular Material.

If you are using Angular Material Library, you need to use Material specific Input controls.

If you are using HTML5 Form with Angular, you can choose form.